# A few questions about express.cookieSession()

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-cookies

On my node.js server (running `express` and `socket.io`), when a person connects, I add them to an array and save their location in the array into their session so each connection has access to their own information like so:

```
session.person_id = people.length;
session.save();
people.push(new Person());
//people[session.person_id] => Person
```

And the only thing that I save in the session is `person_id`. I have been using `express.session()` to handle this, which has been working fine until I started sending information to everyone who is connected at once. As I loop through their connections and get their sessions, sometimes (I can't figure out how to dupe the error) `session` exists but not `session.person_id`.

Anyways I'm hoping that by changing how I store the session, it can help me figure out my problem. So I have a few questions that I can't find answers to anywhere.

1. **Where is the cookie from express.cookieSession() stored? Server-side or client-side?**
2. **Does express.cookieSession() allow for multiple servers running behind a load-balancer?**
3. **Is it possible for a user to manipulate session data when using express.cookieSession()?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Where is the cookie from express.cookieSession() stored? Server-side or client-side?

The cookie is sent on the replies from the server, and the browser sends that cookie back with each request.

2 - Does express.cookieSession() allow for multiple servers running behind a load-balancer?

Yes, if you use a shared store (like RedisStore)

3 - Is it possible for a user to manipulate session data when using express.cookieSession()?

Not if you use signed cookies (the default for session cookies in express when you provide a secret when initializing the session.

```
var redis = require('redis').createClient();
app.use(express.session({
  secret: "some random string",
  store: new RedisStore({client: redis})
  }));
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. I thought the only way to use stores was to use `express.session()` as your example shows but that `express.cookieSession()` [doesn't use stores](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession)?

Comment: this is using the connect session, not the one provided by express (which extends connect).  And uses https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

Comment: `express.session` and `connect.session` are the exact same function. `express.cookieSession` and `connect.cookieSession` are the exact same function as well. I wanted to know about `.cookieSession` and you answered saying to use RedisStore which can only be done by using `.session`. So it seems that question 2 and 3 have gone unanswered. Could you please clarify those two?

Comment: cookieSession is limited in size (4K including name, expiration, and encoding) but stores all in the cookie, so this would work for 2.  cookieSession signs its cookies as well (3).  But I would not use cookieSession, even if you encrypt the content of the cookie.

Comment: Hmm ok. So `cookieSession` can be used just as well as `session` with `RedisStore` but the latter is more secure?

Comment: and can store a lot more data.  So if you only store person_id, that may be ok.  no worse than storing session_id.  But sooner or later, you are going to find you need to store other bits...  But you can switch implementation later.

Comment: For number 2, cookieSession sends the data back to the server for every request, why do we need Redis in order to run multiple servers behind a load balancer?

Comment: if you are sure all your cookies are going to stay below the 4Kb limit, technically, you don't need a shared session, but that could be a bit risky.

Comment: #2 doesn't quite make sense to me. By using express.cookieSession everything is passed to and from the server in the HTTP header. Nothing is stored on the server memory so there is no use for a RedisStore, which makes sense only when using express.session.

Comment: @PascalBelloncle If the cookie session secret is somehow revealed, can the user then manipulate the session?

Comment: @apparatix if the cookie session is captured by someone, they can then do anything a logged in user can do.  Unless you have endpoints to manipulate the session directly, they could only indirectly affect the session based on what you allow logged in users to do (presumably quite a lot).  Using SSL would greatly reduce the chance of this happening.  And timing out sessions quickly is an other way to reduce this.

Comment: @PascalBelloncle Do you mean if the cookie _secret_ is captured?

Comment: no, the cookie itself, which has the session id and a signature based on the secret.  You don't need the secret, unless you want to fake a session (not too useful since there would be no corresponding session on the server.